# I want bat file to ask if it can make changes on the computer

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-registry, administrator

(I don't speak English. Hope you understand)

Hi, I have a .bat file, which edits the registry. I always must right-click and run it as administrator. Then it will ask, if I want to allow the program to make changes on my computer. I want the file to ask this question automatically when I open it. Is there any way to do it? Or any other way(e.g. iexpress)?

Thank you for the answers, Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done:

- via a shortcut:

  1. Create a shortcut for the `.bat` file → Right-click shortcut → *Properties*
  2. Tab: *Shortcut* → *Advanced* → *Run as Administrator* → OK
- from code within the script using [`ShellExecute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea): <sup>*([explanation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch))*</sup> 
   [How do you run a command as an administrator from the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5969764/6819406)

  > ```cmd
  > @if (1==1) @if(1==0) @ELSE
  >   @echo off&SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
  >
  >   >nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"||(
  >     cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"
  >     @goto :EOF
  >   )
  >
  >   echo.Performing admin tasks...
  >     :: # call foo.exe
  >
  >   @goto :EOF
  >
  > @end @ELSE
  >   ShA=new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application")
  >   ShA.ShellExecute("cmd.exe","/c \""+WScript.ScriptFullName+"\"","","runas",5);
  >
  > @end
  > ```

Comment: @Andrew in case you'd like to do so without creating a shortcut, I added links and quoted info on how to do so directly within the script itself.